# Question regarding the theorem of turning tangents

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, curves

I am reading Do Carmo's Differential geometry of curves and surfaces currently. I'm on chapter's 4-4 and 4-5 where the 4-4 talks about parallel transport/covariant derivatives and the 4-5 talks about the gauss bonnet theorem.

Before proving the local gauss-bonnet theorem, the author introduces the theorem of turning tangents which is said to be a result in topology. The theorem being

$\sum_{i=0}^k (\phi_i (t+1) - \phi_i(t)) + \sum_{i=0}^k \theta_i = \pm2\pi$

I think I intuitively understand this formula. The first summation really just measures the change in the angle of the tangent vector to the curve as it moves along one of it's piecewise parts. The second term for theta is the external angle that accounts for the sharp turns at these piecewise junctions.

What I don't understand is the definition of phi. Phi is chosen to be the angle between the tangent vector the curve and one of the coordinate basis vectors, for example, $x_u$.

Why would this be the case? I would think that the correct definition for phi is that it would measure the angle between the tangent vector to the curve, and any parallel direction being transported along the curve. Mainly because when I'm thinking about this picture in flat space, we measure the turning angle as the angle between the tangent vector and any parallel direction.

Comment: The point is that the coordinate basis vectors are globally defined on the open set containing the curve, and so make a good reference frame. If you start parallel translating a particular frame around the curve, then you will have to take into account the turning of that parallel frame (i.e., the geodesic curvature of your particular curve). You might look at section 1 of chapter 3 of my differential geometry text (freely linked in my profile) for a somewhat different exposition.

Comment: @TedShifrin I will look at the link you provided. Thank you.